# How to customize loss function in keras based on the y_true

Tags: keras, deep-learning, loss

I want to custom a loss function based on the y_true values. y_true is a binary value. For each mini-batch, I want to treat y_true==0 and y_true==1 differently. Currently, I have:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    zero = tf.fill(tf.shape(y_true_f), 0.0)
    one = tf.fill(tf.shape(y_true_f), 1.0)
    mask_0 = tf.equal(y_true_f,zero)
    mask_1 = tf.equal(y_true_f,one)
    y_pred_1 = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred_f,mask_1)
    y_pred_0 = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred_f,mask_0)
    y_true_1 = tf.boolean_mask(y_true_f,mask_1)
    y_true_0 = tf.boolean_mask(y_true_f,mask_0)
    loss1 = K.binary_crossentropy(y_true_1,y_pred_1)
    loss0 = K.binary_crossentropy(y_true_0,y_pred_0)
    loss = loss1 +a*loss0 # a is an arbitrary number
```

However, I got an nan loss error. I guess it is because I am training on an imbalance data where only a few cases having y_true==1. So when there is no y_true==1 in this minibatch, there is nan. I want to add if condition based on the shape of mask_1. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with the same technique as cross entropy loss function. Here is the function `loss = ((y_true)*(Loss1)) + ((1 - y_true)*(Loss2))`, so if your `y_true = 0`, first term will be equal to zero and result in `loss = ((0)*Loss1) + ((1 - 0)*Loss2) = Loss2`. If your `y_true = 1` , your second term will become zero, `loss = ((1)*Loss1) + ((1 - 1)*Loss2) = Loss1`

Therefore, you can have 2 Loss function depend on your `y_true = {0,1}`